# Load multiple svn repositories from a single dump file

Tags: svn, import

I have an svn dump file from our old server. This file contains multiple repositories. How can i import this dump file back into a new svn server?

I tried next:

```
svnadmin create test
svnadmin load test < dumpfile
```

Next error occurs: 
svnadmin:E140001: Malformed dumpfile header 'Audio_Tester.dmp'

Think that the problem occurs because of the multiple repositories which are in one dumpfile

Thanks.
Willem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import a dump file that contains multiple repositories. You should dump each repository to it's own file and then load them one by one.

Comment: Thanks. That's bad news.. i hope there is a way to get each repository out of my dump backup file. The original svn server isn't available anymore. Do you know a way to get my data out of this dump file?

Comment: Yossi,Thanks. Just found also and old dump from the specific repository which i did need.